# Audio-Issues using Lutris/Wine

Tags: sound, wine, pulseaudio, alsa, steam

i've come a cross a problem with my Audio somehow.
Example: iam currently in a teamspeak3 session but when i now start a game with Lutris/Wine my audio from teamspeak seems to be dead. i have to restart teamspeak to have it work again.

Same goes for Steam's voice, if i start Steam before a lutris-launch my steam loses all headset/microphone capability until i restart it.

Also my sound becomes choppy after 1-2 hours of game play (Path of Exile via Lutris for example) until i toggle the pulseaudio/alsa one time - but that might be another question/problem.

System:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- no special sound setup done after installing
- using a usb-connected headset (Teufel-CAGE)
- Alsa with PulseAudio in use

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution for the destroyed audio in running programs.

Lutris has a "reset PulseAudio" option under System-Configuration which seems to be the culprit.

I hope this helps someone else using lutris + any voice programs in background

Comment: Restaring pulse audio by `pulseadio -k` from terminla works as well. Thank you for a strong hint.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and find the line containing `load-module module-udev-detect` then add add `tsched=0`

Your new line should look like:

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

For further informations: [wiki.ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/performance)

Comment: tried it out, audio in running programs still breaks(until restarting the program) when starting something through lutris